# Catastrophic Exception on ConnectAsync w/in BackgroundTask [UWP]

Tags: win-universal-app, microsoft-band

Trying to do a simple ConnectAsync in a BackgroundTask.
It throws a Catastrophic Exception (0x8000FFFF) which can be seen when "Break on all Exceptions" is turned on. I have even rolled by my source to known good branches and it still does this.

my code:

```cs
IBandClient client = null;
try
{
    client = await BandClientManager.Instance.ConnectAsync(band);
}
catch { }
```

Exception:

> System.Exception occurred
>   Message: Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in Microsoft.Band.Store.dll
>   Additional information: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))

In v20217 the DLL name is `Microsoft.Band.Store_UAP.dll`

The curious thing is even after throwing this exception, `client` still gets populated with an `IBandClient` object.

Seems like we could do better in terms of the exception being thrown (or better yet not throw one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Band SDK documentation](http://developer.microsofthealth.com/Content/docs/Microsoft%20Band%20SDK.pdf) (section 9.3.2) indicates that one might notice an (expected but not blocking) exception when using the SDK within a background task of a Universal application, related to retrieval of the application ID.

Obviously "expected exceptions" are not ideal, but sometimes the design of the underlying platform APIs leave little choice.

Comment: Good info. I'm not doing anything w/ Background Tile Events so I didn't have a reason to read that section just yet. Maybe we should scoot that caveat up in to the doco for ConnectAsync?